# ASP.NET hangs when inserting numbers using texbox control

Tags: c#, sql-server, textbox, sql-insert

I am using asp.net 4.5, C# and SQL Express, with five text boxes. The values passed are numbers between 0 and 99.  When the inserting the numbers using ExecuteNonQuery, the system hangs for 30 seconds or more.

During VS debugging, I verified the data is actually written to the database, however, ExecuteNonQuery never completes.

**I have tried several methods including converting(TryParse and Convert**) with the same results. I also created a simple test page with just five textboxes, but shows the same problem.  This issue fails with hard coding as well as stored procedure. Using the SQLDatasource control works, but prefer to code using C#.  The fields are only used for numbers and will be calculated during reporting.
Note: I'm assuming the value needs converted from a string to a INT.

**Table structure:**

```
          [StatID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Made2PT] [int] NULL, [Missed2PT] [int] NULL,
```

**Stored procedure:**

```
@Made2Pt Int, @Missed2pt Int        
          AS
          BEGIN
      INSERT INTO tblStatsV2(Made2Pt,Missed2pt)     
      VALUES (@Made2Pt,@Missed2pt)
```

**C# code behind sample, Partial Test page with two text boxes**:

```
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Made2Pt", txtMade2PT.Text == "" ? 0 : 
                                          Convert.ToInt32(txtMade2PT.Text));
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Missed2pt",txtMade2PT.Text == "" ? 0 : 
                                          Convert.ToInt32(txtMissed2PT.Text));`
```

**Partial sample code behind from other page:**

```
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 if (int.TryParse(txt2ptMade.Text, out made2PT))
 {
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Made2Pt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = made2PT;
 }
```

I would expect the entry to return in less that a second as my other pages have quick response.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code.... but you are right, this should give an almost instant result. Therefor the issue must lie somewhere else.

Comment: What you describe sounds suspiciously like a deadlock. Are you sure you aren't calling `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

What I didn't do was test my issue on different browsers(Edge, Chrome, Opera...).. I did fix the stored procedure by adding local variables, but this did not eliminate the issue.  I discovered that issue only fails with Microsoft Edge. After scanning Microsoft's support, one fix was to remove a KB patch.. Each browser processes the data differently, so you can expect different results on performance issues. Hope this helps..